How to substitute NAs value in a data.table from values in another
I have two data.tables. One has some NA values which I want to replace with the value from the same position (row / col) of the second data.table.
I can do it for each column separately. Is there a way to do all columns in one go?
Reprex:
x <- data.table(
  a = runif(10),
  b = runif(10)
)

x[3, a := NA]
x[7, a := NA]
x[5, b := NA]

y <- data.table(
  a = runif(10)*100,
  b = runif(10)*100
)

# this works but I have to go row by row
x[is.na(a), a := y[is.na(x$a), a]]
x[is.na(b), b := y[is.na(x$b), b]]


# this also works but I'm not sure is the best way
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  x[[i]] <- ifelse(is.na(x[[i]]), y[[i]], x[[i]])
}


Benchmarks included after all comments
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

x <- data.table(
  a = runif(10),
  b = runif(10)
)

x[3, a := NA]
x[7, a := NA]
x[5, b := NA]

y <- data.table(
  a = runif(10)*100,
  b = runif(10)*100
)

x <- x[rep(1:10,1e4), rep(1:2,50), with=FALSE]
y <- y[rep(1:10,1e4), rep(1:2,50), with=FALSE]

# this works but I have to go row by row
# x[is.na(a), a := y[is.na(x$a), a]]
# x[is.na(b), b := y[is.na(x$b), b]]


# # this also works but I'm not sure is the best way
# for (i in seq_along(x)) {
#   x[[i]] <- ifelse(is.na(x[[i]]), y[[i]], x[[i]])
# }

# testing the solutions given by thelatemail and Adriano
z <- copy(x)

bm <- microbenchmark(
  'latemail' = as.data.table(Map(fcoalesce, x, y)),
  'adriano' = y * is.na(x) + x[ , lapply(.SD, \(i) ifelse(is.na(i), 0, i))],
  'loop' = {
    # z <- copy(x)
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
      z[[i]] <- ifelse(is.na(x[[i]]), y[[i]], x[[i]])
    }
  },
  'loop_set' = {
    # z <- copy(x)
    for(col in seq_along(z)) {
      sel <- which(is.na(x[[col]]))
      set(z, i = sel, j = col, value = y[[col]][sel])
    }
    
  }
)

bm
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#>  latemail  21.18020  23.42095  31.46701  25.58454  36.78618  68.43255   100
#>   adriano 518.86065 625.29776 651.63715 646.92010 676.09935 893.32570   100
#>      loop 126.26689 135.11014 144.93929 139.88824 150.09446 184.89310   100
#>  loop_set  32.82947  34.51500  39.49935  35.76292  39.03663 104.21157   100


Generalisably, using Map to align the columns, and fcoalesce to fast-coalesce the values together:
as.data.table(Map(fcoalesce, x, y))
##              a           b
##          <num>       <num>
## 1:  0.50747820  0.65165567
## 2:  0.30676851  0.56773775
## 3: 77.51098964  0.11350898
## 4:  0.69310208  0.59592531
## 5:  0.08513597 42.26376070
## 6:  0.22543662  0.42880942
## 7: 83.82876653  0.05190332
## 8:  0.27230507  0.26417767
## 9:  0.61582931  0.39879073
##10:  0.42967153  0.83613414

You could also do it inside x[], but that might be risky if you have a variable with the name y as well as the dataset y:
x[, Map(fcoalesce, .SD, y)]

(using set.seed(10) as per Adriano's answer)
If you wanted to use the looping method, take advantage of the speedup of set to overwrite the columns:
for(col in seq_along(x)) {
    sel <- which(is.na(x[[col]]))
    set(x, i = sel, j = col, value = y[[col]][sel])
}


I might have done the benchmark wrong, But it looks like there is just a small difference between using set or not. I've updated my question with the solution

@Daniel - try it with something bigger like x <- x[rep(1:10,1e5), rep(1:2,50), with=FALSE]; y <- y[rep(1:10,1e5), rep(1:2,50), with=FALSE] - benchmarks on 10 rows and 2 columns for data.table won't capture the benefits I don't reckon.

@Daniel - Also, don't include the copy() as part of the benchmark, as that is probably a chunk of the timing.

You are right, copy() takes a long time. I included it because I though that if I didn't, it would keep writing over the same object and mess up the benchmark. But I updated the benchmark and now we see the differences

Definitely not a data.table connoisseur here, but look for .SD and .SDcols arguments.
Here's one alternative:
set.seed(10) # For `x` and `y` 

z <- y * is.na(x) + x[ , lapply(.SD, replace_na, 0)]

Output:
> z
              a           b
          <num>       <num>
 1:  0.50747820  0.65165567
 2:  0.30676851  0.56773775
 3: 77.51098964  0.11350898
 4:  0.69310208  0.59592531
 5:  0.08513597 42.26376070
 6:  0.22543662  0.42880942
 7: 83.82876653  0.05190332
 8:  0.27230507  0.26417767
 9:  0.61582931  0.39879073
10:  0.42967153  0.83613414


Beautiful solution! Never though of multiplying by a binary mask and than adding both tables. I made a small change to your code:
y * is.na(x) + x[ , lapply(.SD, \(i) ifelse(is.na(i), 0, i))]

Your attempted solution gave me the idea. Not the faster, but not the slowest!
